# VMware ESXi 5.5 ホストOSへ接続出来ない

Tags: vmware

VMware ESXi 5.5 で稼働しているホストOSが突然pingダウンし接続出来ない状態となりました。

vSphere clientよりログインを試みるも接続できませんが、配下のゲストOSについてはpingダウンしておらず、リモートデスクトップでログインもできる状態です。

改善のために実施したことについては現状特にございません。(シャットダウンや再起動については稼働中のためすぐに実施できず後ほど実施予定です。)
この場合考えられる原因はございますでしょうか？

こういったシステムに疎く伝わりずらいかと思いますが、ご存知の方回答お願い致します。

Answer (score 0):

単なる仮説ですが、

1. ESXiのARP応答がない、あるいは不正なものになっていることが考えられます。
2. ゲートウェイになっているL3SWのARPテーブルがおかしくなっていることも考えられます。

1の場合はESXiが原因と思いますが、2の場合はネットワーク機器の問題の可能性があるので、ESXiの再起動では状態が回復しない可能性があると思います。(その場合、L3SWのARPテーブルをクリアするか、再起動する等の対処になると思います)

いかがでしょうか?